# Android HummingBad malware - can it install a rootkit on a non-rooted phone?

Tags: android, security, malware

The "HummingBad" malware is in the news right now, and not in a good way.   In researching the topic, I found [this report](https://www.checkpoint.com/press/2016/threat-mobile-malware-continues-grow-hummingbad-attacks-move-check-point-research-rankings/) from CheckPoint.  Here is a quote describing HummingBad:

> HummingBad – Android malware that establishes a persistent rootkit on the device, installs fraudulent applications, and enables additional malicious activity such as installing a key-logger, stealing credentials and bypassing encrypted email containers used by enterprises.

Can a malware app somehow find its way around the Android "sandbox" architecture to infect a phone?   Or is the spread of this malware restricted to customers who buy rooted phones?

Comment: This malware infects rooted devices only or it can affect non-rooted devices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be able to attack rooted devices directly, but also has several "Plan B" attack methods as well.  For non-rooted devices, it relies on tricking the user into approving the installation.

Here is the link to CheckPoint's recent article on HummingBad:
http://blog.checkpoint.com/2016/07/01/from-hummingbad-to-worse-new-in-depth-details-and-analysis-of-the-hummingbad-andriod-malware-campaign/

and here is a link to their 24-page report:
http://blog.checkpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/HummingBad-Research-report_FINAL-62916.pdf

Comment: It appears that there are other vulnerabilities:  https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2016-5195 and see also:  https://dirtycow.ninja/